# How to reset the state to it's initial state in redux store?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

In redux store I have set initial state to some value as shown below:

```
const search_initial_state = {
FilterItem:18
}
```

I am changing this state value in another function manually
But after click on reset button I want to set "FilterItem" state to it's initial value.(i.e. 18)

Comment: can you please post the code of your reducer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If i understood you correctly, you want to reset only one value to its original/initial value.

Define an action creator that dispatches action type of RESET_FILTER_ITEM and then whenever you want to reset filter item dispatch this action.

```
const resetFilterItem = () {
    return {
      type: "RESET_FILTER_ITEM"
    }
}
```

and your reducer will look like this after implementing reset case

```
const myReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
   switch(action.type){
      case "OTHER_CASE":
        return {...state}
      case "RESET_FILTER_ITEM":
        return {
           ...state,
           FilterItem: initialState.FilterItem
        }
      default:
        return state  
   }
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 2):

Reducers will update their state when an action has been dispatched for them to process. So likewise, you have to dispatch an action that tells your reducer to return the initial state.

```
//Reducer code
const initialState = {}

const myReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
   switch(action.type){
      case "FILTER_ITEM":
        return {...someUpdatedState}
      case "RESET_ITEM":
        return initialState
      default:
        return state
  }
}
```

Your reducer will return a new state depending on the action type.

So just define an action creator that dispatches action type of `RESET_ITEM` or something else you may want to call it. Then use it when you want to reset.

```
const resetItem = () => {
   return {
      type: "RESET_ITEM"
   }
}
```

Comment: But if in initialState array I have many states and I want to reset only one state to its initial state,then how I can set it?

Comment: @NikitaWagh sorry for the lag. I believe with above code it will only effect one state in your store. Is that what you're looking for?